# NUnit console can't load assembly for serialization test

Tags: serialization, nunit, nunit-console

Error message:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Unable to find
>   assembly 'MyCompany.Plates, Version=12.15.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=0b9f95a95d107d22'.
>   +++++++++++++++++++ STACK TRACE: at  System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()

There are two DLL files:

**PlatesTests.dll** and **MyCompany.Plates.dll**

The tests are all in `PlatesTests.dll`. The objects being serialized are in `MyCompany.Plates.dll`.

When run by passing `PlatesTests.dll` to `nunit-console.exe`, everything passes.

However, our build system uses a .nunit file as under:

```
<NUnitProject>
  <Settings activeconfig="Default" />
  <Config name="Default" binpathtype="Auto">
    <assembly path="..\..\Build Products\ReleaseTests\PlatesTests.dll" />
   </Config>
</NUnitProject>
```

And when the nunit-console is run against this .nunit file, it gives the above error.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to run the console project with /noshadow

From [the documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.5)

> The /noshadow option disables shadow copying of the assembly in order to provide improved performance.

This shadow copying sometimes causes assembly loading to fail for projects.

Comment: OK, where is it trying to load the MyCompany.Plates from? Can you use fusion log viewer to check?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting the **appbase** on the `.nunit` setting file to point to where `PlatesTests.dll` and `MyCompany.Plates.dll` are both located.

The new file looks like this:

```
<NUnitProject>
  <Settings activeconfig="Default" appbase="..\..\Build Products\ReleaseTests" />
  <Config name="Default" binpathtype="Auto">
    <assembly path="..\..\Build Products\ReleaseTests\PlatesTests.dll" />
  </Config>
</NUnitProject>
```